# How to add Newtonsoft.Json version 6.0.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have insalled Newtonsoft.Json dll version package 7.0.1 and set reference every where needed,also I have dll of this in bin directory, project/solution able to build successfully. even though I got following error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Line 76:
>   WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

I haver tried to uninsatll package from solution,but it gives error like,

> Unable to uninstall 'Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1' because
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3' depends on it.

so what to do in such case. I am using asp.netmvc4 with entity framework and webapi.

Comment: Is there any indication of what's *looking* for Json.NET 6.0?

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3 requires Newtonsoft.Json >= 6.0.4 only. So you can try Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 6.0.4 in package manager console

Comment: @haz when I trying to install 6.04 ,it gives message that newtonsoft.json version 7.0.1 can't updated. when I trying to uninstall newtonsoft.json version 7.0.1 it gives error like "Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1' because 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3' depends on it." . I am totally hanged.

Comment: So is there *no* more error information? No fuller stack trace? You might want to try fusion logging to see what's causing this...

Comment: If you check all packages and not found any one depends on Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1, you should uninstall Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3 first, then Newtonsoft.Json. After that, you only need to install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3, all its dependencies will be added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is a low quality fix, but something you can try: in your web.config file, after `<assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"`..., change the binding redirect to map to the version you have installed:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.1.0" newVersion="7.0.1.0" />
```

Comment: Works, Life Saver!